# Firemonkey StringGrid tab and arrow keys are not working

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, stringgrid

I want to do some work with FM StringGrid, everything works fine but the problem I have is the arrow keys + tab key, they don't work as expected, e.g. if I press the tab key the whole grid loses the focus or if I press one of the arrow keys (up, down, left, right) it just doesn't do anything, in the VCL StringGid goTab option must be set to true to be able to use the tab key which is not the case in FM, anybody faced the same issue? or have any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: please show some of your code